# Run a command in GNU Screen when the window changes

Tags: script, gnu-screen, zsh

Is it possible to execute a screen command when the user changes the window?

I have my current working directory in my hardstatus by using zsh's precmd() feature to change screen's working directory to zsh's working directory when a command runs. But since zsh doesn't run a command when the window changes, the working directory in my hardstatus doesn't update to the zsh instance in the new window (obviously).

My thinking is that if I can get screen to execute a :chdir when the window changes, I can have zsh storing its working directory somewhere or something along those lines and have screen read it and change to that when the window changes. (There's likely a more efficient solution, that's just what I came up with off the top of my head.)

Comment: This sounds like a complicated thing.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: As stated, I want the working directory of the contained shell in my hardstatus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the working directory of the contained shell in my hardstatus.

Possible solution: rewrite `precmd()` to instead set the Xterm title, using `printf "\e]0;%s\007" "$PWD"`. (I like `${PWD/#$HOME/~}`.)

When used inside `screen`, this will actually update hardstatus text.

Comment: It's working exactly as I expect currently. i.e. when I run a command my hardstatus is updated with zsh's working directory. The problem is when I change windows, the zsh instance in that window doesn't update until a command is run.

Comment: @Shadow: Have you at least read the post?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the fact that precmd is being used at all. precmd doesnt get run when screen switches windows.

Comment: @Shadow: It isn't a problem. Screen remembers the 'titles' of every window (it's part of its job), so once the precmd sets a title, it will be kept even if you switch to another window and back. All you have to do is configure screen's hardstatus to display the title of currently selected window.